# Visualhg on visual studio 2015: commands not working

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visualhg

On Windows 10, I installed VisualHg on Visual studio 2015 community edition and configured my environment to use it as source control.

Right-click context menu just show up fine, but when I click on some menu item, nothing happen (e.g.: "History", "Repo browser", etc.).

Note: Visual Studio 2015 is running as administrator.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I configured Hg workbench to always run as administrator too (in "Properties", tab "Compatibility", check the "Run this program as an administrator"):

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue running Visual Studio 2013 (as Administrator) and this fixed it. Thanks!